# Parsing dictionary from plist into array in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, plist

Here is the `plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Applications</key>
    <string>应用程序</string>
    <key>Compositions</key>
    <string>Compositions</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I use `PlistBuddy` in **bash** to print this `plist`. And I got the result like this:

```
Dict {
    Applications = 应用程序
    Compositions = Compositions
}
```

How can I parse string above into an array like this in **bash**?

```
array[0]="应用程序" array[1]="Compositions"
```

Comment: What do you want in your array? `array[0]="应用程序"` and `array[1]="Compositions"` or as an associative array `array[Applications]="应用程序"` and `array[Compositions]="Compositions"`?

Comment: `array[0]="应用程序"` is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's what you really wanted but in your case it will create an array for you of what you wanted:

```
dict=($(awk '/=/{ print $3 }' <<< "$(your plist result here)"))
```

Test:

```
echo "${dict[@]}"
```

Output:

```
应用程序 Compositions
```

Answer (score 2):

For a pure bash solution, the easiest way to parse the plist file, in the absence of a plist parser (and absent using `sed` or `awk`), is to read the plist file and add the entries using **parameter expansion/substring extraction** to get the actual values from the script lines. An example would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

test -n "$1" -a -r "$1" || {
    printf "\nerror: invalid input.  Usage:  %s plist_file\n\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

declare -a plarray

while read -r line || test -n "$line" ; do
    test "${line:0:8}" = "<string>" || continue
    tmp="${line//<string>/}"
    tmp="${tmp//<\/string>/}"
    plarray+=( "$tmp" )
done <"$1"

for ((i=0; i<${#plarray[@]}; i++)); do
    printf " array[%d]=\"%s\"\n" "$i" "${plarray[i]}"
done

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
$ bash readplist.sh dat/plist.txt
 array[0]="应用程序"
 array[1]="Compositions"
```

**Note:** parsing text with bash can be tricky, if there is a plist/xml parser, it should be used as a first choice to extract the values.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me (Thanks to BallPython)

```
#!/bin/bash
RootDir=/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations/zh_CN.lproj
FileName=SystemFolderLocalizations.strings
PB=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy

list=`$PB -c "Print" $RootDir/$FileName`

items=`awk -F" = " '
{
    if ($0 ~ /[{}]/){}
    else{printf $1","}
}' <<< "${list}"`

IFS=',' read -ra array <<< "$items"

for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back-tics.  Use parentheses like this: `item=$(awk -F" = " '<code>')`

Comment: it would work, but too much excess. I do prefer oneliners where it's possible.